# automatic traffic light sequence in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the code below which changes between three images, a red amber and green traffic light and each time i click the button it changes between the lights. what i would like to know is if there is a way i can click the button once and the sequence will run by its self. red to amber to green pause slightly then go to amber then red again and that will happen each time you click the button. is it possible to do and how may i ask so that i can try and code it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Head>
<script>
var trafficlights=['redlight.png','yellowlight.png','greenlight.png','yellowlight.png'];
var num=1


function lightsequence(){
    document.getElementById('light').src = trafficlights[num++ % trafficlights.length];
}
</script>
</Head>
<body>
<img id="light" src="redlight.png">
<button onclick="lightsequence()">Change Lights</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, you would use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    var num = 0;
    var timeoutId = 0;    
    function lightsequence(){
        if (num >= trafficlights.length) {
                num = 0;
        }

        document.getElementById('light').src = trafficlights[num];
        num += 1;
    }

    function startTL() {
        lightsequence(); // Run once first.
        timeoutId = setInterval(lightsequence, 1000); // Run every second
    }
```

Comment: it does the exact same thing as my current code does, it just changes the lights every time i click the button

Comment: @MATTHEWPARKER I've modified the answer abit. The onclick function of your button should call startTL() function. The setInterval should keep calling the lightsequence function every second in a loop and will only stop when you call clearInterval(timeoutId)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the function `lightsequence`:

```
if (num % trafficlights.length != 1)
    window.setTimeout(lightsequence, 500);
```

I applied it below, using a div with background color instead of images:

```js
var red = '#cc0605';
var yellow = '#fad201';
var green = '#27e833';
var colors = [red, yellow, green, yellow];

var num=1;
function divLight() {
    return document.getElementById('light');
}

function lightsequence(){
    divLight().style.background = colors[num++ % colors.length];
    if (num % colors.length != 1)
        window.setTimeout(lightsequence, 500);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="divLight().style.background = red;">
    <div id="light" style="width:20px;height:20px"></div>
    <button onclick="lightsequence()">Change Lights</button>
</body>
</html>
```